# Hibernate relation between a sub table and related table

Tags: java, hibernate

Have a relation between a sub table and a related table using the primary table. Any thoughts about how to go about the hibernate relation.

A <---> B (One to One relation) B is a sub-table of A.

B <---> C (B has One to Many Relation with C Using A)

Comment: What do you mean by "sub-table". Is it like every record in B has an equivalent in A and adds additional data? And do C records have a foreign key to A or B records? (Your description isn't that clear to me). Could you maybe add a more concrete example and what you'd envision the JPA/Hibernate entities to be?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It not needed in table B in your case. There is `@OneToMany` between A and B.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="A")
public class A {
   ....
   @OneToMany(mappedBy="a")
   private B b;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="C")
public class C {
   ...
   @OneToOne
   @JoinColumn(name="ref_to_a")
   private A a;
}
```

Additional table B is required if `@ManyToMany` association take place.